# How can i use Jvectormap-next with angular 5

Tags: jquery, angular5

I am trying to implement jvectormap in my angular 5 Project, but i am not being able to. this is what i have in the component file:

I used the following command to install JVectormap-next :

> npm install jvectormap-next --save

```
require('jvectormap-next')($); // <----- Error here 


// render the map
let gdpData = {
    'AF': 16.63,
    'AL': 11.58,
    'DZ': 158.97,
    // ...
}

$('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    series: {
        regions: [{
            values: gdpData,
            scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
        }]
    },
    onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
        el.html(el.html()+' (GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')');
    }
});
```

and before the @Component tag, i am also declaring:

```
import "jvectormap-next";
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
```

And this is my html file:

```
<div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

But i am getting error in the first line :

> [ts] Identifier expected.

but i don't know how can i solve that, i don't really use JQuery that much, so maybe i am doing something that is basic really wrong, i don't know, If someone could point me in the right direction i would be really glad.
Thank you!

Comment: anyone able to help?